# Some scholars says that you cannot make the plural and feminine form of word Allah from arabic linguistic perspective

Tags: historical-linguistics, linguistic-typology, comparative-linguistics, arabic, history-of-linguistics

Is it possible from arabic linguistic perspective to make the plural and feminine form of word الله? for example اللهون plural form of word الله and اللت feminine form of word الله because in Arabic, the regular way of making a plural for a masculine noun is adding the suffix -ūn[a] (for the nominative) at the end and To make a masculine word feminine usually a ة (h/t) is added to the end of the word so when you add ون to الله it becomes اللهون plural form of الله and when you add ت or ة to the end of the word then it becomes feminine for example when we add ت to الله it becomes اللت feminine form of word الله so when it is possible to make plural and feminine forms of word الله so why some scholars says الله is the unique word which you cannot make plural or feminine form from arabic linguistic perspective?

Comment: There is no _linguistic_ reason why a particular word shouldn't take all the desinences proper to its class. It nevertheless sometimes happens that a form which might exist doesn't exist; eg the English word _pants_ has no singular. If "scholars" claim that such a word is the "unique" example of such a limitation, I would suspect that their "linguistics" was rather different from what the rest of the world means by linguistics.

Answer (score 2):

The indefinite form *ilāh* (إله) “a god” has a broken plural that you can find in the dictionary:  *ālihah* (آلهة).  A definite plural *al-ālihah* meaning “the gods” would not make sense, except to a polytheist.  (These are the forms you would hear at a natural pause, without case endings.)  Few nouns, other than verbal nouns and participles, form regular plurals with *-uuna/iina* or *-aat*.